# Invalid arguments Candidates are: void minEnclosingCircle(const cv::_InputArray &, cv::Point_<float> &, float &)

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I am detecting circles in Android by using contours in JNI but getting an error:

```
std::vector<Point2f&> center(contours.size() );
std::vector<float&> radius(contours.size() );

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
  cv::approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]),Mat(contours_poly[i]), 3, true );
  boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
  minEnclosingCircle(Mat(contours_poly[i]),center[i],radius[i]);
}
```

> Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void minEnclosingCircle(const cv::*InputArray &, cv::Point* &, float &)'

What does that mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Mine certainly doesn't like your attempt to declare vectors of references.

Comment: please move the references out of your vectors, they're clearly wrong.

Comment: removed... but still not working

Comment: Since you want to learn something, you should actually ask a question instead of just describing your problem.